# How to add multi language support to a page (French fanpage for those using french facebook, english fanpage for those using EN facebook)

Tags: facebook-page

I'm trying to have my fanpage's "welcome" page to show a different video and lines of text wether they are using french settings on facebook or english. So those using the french facebook UI will see the french video and text below and those using the default english will see the default english page.

Hopefully someone can point me to some help, I really am not sure how ot do this...

Answer (score 0):

Use `locale` property of Graph User object if you have a custom app tab. Info here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Also, would be good to read this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/

I don't think you can translate the non-app facebook page at the moment.

Comment: I think "languages" would work better, since in Canada you have English and French speaking people. However I don't want the app page to be translated, I have already 2 different html pages (one french, one english). I just want to to display the english html content if the users language is "EN" and french if it is "FR".

Answer (score 0):

When a user access the fanpage's tab, the application that provides the tab content get 'signed_request' from Facebook. In signed_request, there is 'user.locale' property. Just use it to determine what locale code the user is using.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: Is there somewhere I can find an example PHP code that can parse different html depending on the user.locale property? (Maybe it's the same code as those who use different html for those who liked and those who did not like?) So "FR_CA" if the person is french and from Canada and the rest all get the english version? Aka something like If FR_CA then use this html --> (french images,videos etc) if not "FR_CA" then use this html --> (english images,videos etc)                          Besides html I do not really know much about PHP and how it would understand facebook's user.locale code...

Comment: I'm not good at php. I'd like to recommend to check 'gettext' for php. Here are some links.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php
http://mel.melaxis.com/devblog/2005/08/06/localizing-php-web-sites-using-gettext/